# Finding period of a tangent graph

Tags: trigonometry

> For example, $y= - \cot 4t$

I understand that period of function $f(t)$ is the smallest positive number $p$ such that $f(t+p)= f(t)$ for every value of $t$

How do I apply this fact to find the period? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying angle-sum identities,
$$\cot(4(t+p)) = \frac{\cos(4(t+p))}{\sin(4(t+p))} = \frac{\cos(4t)\cos(4p)-\sin(4t)\sin(4p)}{\cos(4t)\sin(4p)+\sin(4t)\cos(4p)} \quad != \quad \frac{\cos(4t)}{\sin(4t)}.$$

To eliminate the terms multiplying $\sin(4p)$ in the numerator in the middle fraction, the smallest positive $p$ that will work is $p = \pi/4$.

Hence, the period is $\pi/4$.